# Stored procedure syntax error while trying to query multiple databases

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have got a multi-tenant database setup. I would like to read users table for each database and combine the results. e.g. traditionally, I would do something like;

```
SELECT * FROM database1.users 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM database2.users
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM database3.users
```

However, as the databases are assigned dynamically. I tried to create a stored procedure which is rather simple where I get a list of all databases and then try to get the information related to the users' table using the cursor. Here is the code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `getAllUsers`()
DETERMINISTIC
COMMENT 'test'
BEGIN
  DECLARE queryString TEXT DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE tenant_db_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE tenant_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT (table_schema) FROM 
     information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema LIKE 'tenant%';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN tenant_cursor;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH tenant_cursor INTO tenant_db_id;
    IF done = 1 THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF queryString != '' THEN
        SET queryString = CONCAT(queryString, ' UNION ALL ');
    END IF;
    SET queryString = CONCAT(queryString, ' SELECT * FROM ', tenant_db_id, '.users');
  END LOOP;
   CLOSE tenant_cursor;

   SET @qStr = queryString;

  PREPARE stmt FROM @qStr;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET @qStr = NULL;
END
```

However, I keep on getting the syntax error and I have exhausted all options.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-e6ca-4fe6-ae67-f88860cea33a.users UNION ALL  SELECT * FROM tenant41c01b27-ca35-' at line 1, Time: 0.024000s

Comment: To troubleshoot this, I would check the full error message, because syntax errors indicate exactly where the syntax problem occurs in the query. Also instead of assigning `@sStr = NULL` it would be helpful to see the full query string, because viewing it could make the mistake clear. For example, do any of your schema names have special characters, or SQL reserved words?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Are you getting the syntax error when you define the procedure or when you call it?

Comment: can you post the complete error message and also tell where do you run the code phpmyadmin?

Comment: Do you use `DELIMITER` before defining the procedure so that `;` doesn't end the definition?

Comment: The question got downvoted for some reason. Thanks whoever you are.  here is the
error in full
`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-e6ca-4fe6-ae67-f88860cea33a.users UNION ALL  SELECT * FROM tenant41c01b27-ca35-' at line 1, Time: 0.024000s`

Comment: @Barmar i get the error when i try to run the procedure

Comment: @nbk I am running it in navicat

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate. The linked question is about field names, but the same answer applies to any identifiers (table names, schema names, etc.). I recommend you read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: @BillKarwin it's easy once you know what the issue is. Had I known that it was to do with hyphens, I wouldn't have asked the question here. Besides, your comment came after Barmer had answered the question. Why didn't you point it out in first place? Be welcoming and encouraging to people who ask questions rather than scoring points by moderating.

Comment: I mean no disrespect. I voted to close the question less than 10 minutes after you provided the error message that I requested. It's proper usage of Stack Overflow to close questions that are duplicates. The Help Center says so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 2):

Your schema names contain `-`, so you need to quote them with backticks. Change

```
    SET queryString = CONCAT(queryString, ' SELECT * FROM ', tenant_db_id, '.users');
```

to

```
    SET queryString = CONCAT(queryString, ' SELECT * FROM `', tenant_db_id, '`.users');
```